# Which field describes reporter of a Salesforce Case

Tags: rest, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

AS in every ticket we create normally programmatically, we do have a reporter and assignee of ticket. But in sales-force API documentation I could not find any field which describes Reporter of Case.

Also, there is no field to specify project Id against which we can create a case.

Is this the limitation of the Salesforce ITSM services or am I missing something.

Reference link
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/api-explorer/sobject/Case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A case is normally associated with an Account (AccountID) record and a Contact (ContactId) record.  Those record indicate the "reporter" of your case.

Comment: thanks Gareth Jordan, And what about Project Id for case? Are all cases in Salesforce Orphaned?

Comment: Did you mean ParentId?  If you did ParentId is the parent case for example let say you have a case for faulty motherboard, but while looking into that you find a faulty network card, you would make a new case for the network card and set the Parent as the Motherboard case so that it better relates back to the original case.  So for most cases there would not be a parent because the wont relate to a previous case

Comment: No, I am implementing this API for Project management tickets. Cases (tickets) belongs to a perticular Project. Parent case id is different thing.

Comment: Case is created only with AccountId as Reporter. 
Contact id not accepted. Error - 'Account ID: id value of incorrect type: 0038F00000trloDWAU'

Comment: Is that a custom field you created?  There is no way for me to know about custom fields on you case without you specifying that in your question.  Contact Id would be the Id of a contact record, it is a separate field from the AccountId field.  AccountId needs to be the Id of the account record and ContactId needs to be the Id of the Contact record.  You can't add a contactId to a field that expects an AccountId.  If project is a custom object with a lookup on case you would need to add the id of the project to Project_Id__c if the field was called "Project Id"

Comment: got it Gareth Jordan.. Thanks. Yes Project is a custom object  for which we are creating cases for reporting bugs.